# Split models and forms into a subfolder structure Django 2.0+

Tags: django

I want to have the following structure for models and forms inside my app:

```
project/
--------app_name/
-----------------forms/
-----------------------__init__.py
-----------------------a.py
-----------------------b_folder/
--------------------------------__init__.py
--------------------------------b1.py
--------------------------------b2.py
-----------------models/
-----------------------__init__.py
-----------------------a.py
-----------------------b_folder/
--------------------------------__init__.py
--------------------------------b1.py
--------------------------------b2.py
```

Splitting the app into different apps doesn't really make sense in this particular case.

At the moment everything fit into models.py and forms.py but they are around 10k lines each.

The idea will be to be abble to split those monolith into small entities to simplify the code maintenance of the all project.

For the models parts it seems to work: I was able to runserver without any error.

It starts crash when I apply the same method to the forms.

Here is the `__init__.py` content

**forms/__init__.py**

```
from .a import *
from .b_folder import *
```

**forms/b_folder/__init__.py**

```
from .b1 import *
from .b2 import *
```

**models/__init__.py**

```
from .a import *
from .b_folder import *
```

**models/b_folder/__init__.py**

```
from .b1 import *
from .b2 import *
```

*Now, how to import the following?*

**forms/b_folder_b1.py**

```
#how to import the model a or b1?
from app_name.models import AModel, BOneModel
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'BOneModel' from 'app_name.models' (/project/app_name/models/__init__.py)
```

EDIT: 
The error seems to be a typo in my code.
This way is the proper way to make it work, and it doesn't seems to mess with migration at all.

So my question evolve a little bit:

**Is it a "good" design pattern to do it that way?**

Comment: maybe you make a typo here `BOneModel`. Maybe it's `BoneModel`

Comment: This is just a proof of concept exemple I am sure the real project doesn't contain typo

Comment: You try to `B0neModel` to import it doesn't exist. is it?

Comment: You may have a circular import, and `from app_name.models import AModel, BOneModel` is running before `from .b_folder import *` has completed.

Comment: @shafik, you were right there was a snicky typo betwwen a model name and form name